# Notepad++ is recognizing my html.erb files as javascript files! It's messing up my syntax highlighting!

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, syntax-highlighting, notepad++

This is really annoying...it really is messing up my syntax highlighting...
I think it suddenly happened after I deleted one of my javascript_include_tag statements and saved...suddenly the highlighting changed.

This all happened around the time I created my first js.erb file...

Oh yeah: It was working before!!!  I have "erb" already added as a file association/extension to html files...but for some reason, html.erb files are suddenly getting interpreted as javascript files! like, in the bottom left, it says what type of file you are viewing, and when I have an html.erb file open it says "javascript file" which is absurd...it used to say html erb...

Comment: Or Visual Web Developer from Microsoft, it's free as long as you register. Great editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem myself.  Since Rails 3 uses this new js.erb file, at one point, I went to the style configurator and added "erb" as an extension option under "Javascript."  I had already done this for html so html.erb is recognized as html, so apparently notepad++ has this bug in it b/c once I added "erb" to Javascript all html.erb began getting recognized as JS files.  Removing that "erb" to Javascript in the style configurator fixed the problem. :)

Answer (score 8):

You can configure Notepad++ to recognize an .erb (.html.erb or .js.erb) file and associate it with a given language (html).

1. In the menu bar, go to Settings > Style Configurator...
2. In the list labelled "Language:", scroll down to HTML.  Click on it
3. Beneath the lists for Language and Style, there should appear two fields: Default ext and User ext.  Enter 'erb' in the User ext field.
4. Click Save & Close

Now when you open a file with the .erb extension (incl. .js.erb), Notepad++ will automatically apply syntax highlighting for HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Check the post here:

- http://www.thekua.com/atwork/2009/07/file-associations-in-notepad/

It allows you to change the associations.

Comment: No, I get that...the problem is that notepad++ won't recognize the files correctly...it recognize html erc as javascript... :/

Comment: I don't have Notepad++ right now to confirm, but from what I remember if you go and set up the file association for `.erb` (in the picture from the link I posted, input this in User ext: field), you can specify which language it should be "recognized" as. You can add multiple extensions (separate them by space) that need to be recognized as JavaScript. E.g. if you add `js erb` in the User extension text box, it will "recognize" `.js` and `.erb` as JavaScript files.